# How to Enable Status Bar In Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My status bar were visible back then, but after I use package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) and [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)
It gone. [image]

I already try using SystemChrome inside build method or run method doesn't work

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
    SystemUiOverlay.values);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
```

Anyone know what happen?

My build Widget

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
        SystemUiOverlay.values);
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.white));
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: SeedProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: SurgeryProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: CookingProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: FishingProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: CombiningProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: CrystalsProvider(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Grow Guides',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
            primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                textTheme: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white, displayColor: Colors.white),
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white)),
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocale.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: [
            const Locale('en'),
            const Locale('id'),
          ],
          onGenerateRoute: onGenerateRoute,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Growtopia Guides")),
            body: HomePage(),
          )),
    );
  }
```

I'm not sure where the exact problem feel free to ask my code file

Comment: use App bar in Scaffold.        return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(),}

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: Which  file do you want to know? main.dart? because I'm not sure where the exact problem is could be the AndroidManifest

Comment: That's Scaffold with appBar up there

Comment: can you send your code?

Comment: Edited Check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure it out what happen I'll post it here, in case somebody got the same problem like mine. The problem is after I use those packages which I describe, it changed the styles.xml under `android/app/src/main/res/values` some changes were made like :

`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`

That what make my apps went Fullscreen and the status bar went invisible, so I changed it to false and worked just fine. It's totally my fault not checking those changes that were made by packages :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in pubspec.yaml with this (It will disable full screen):

```
flutter_native_splash:
  android_disable_fullscreen: true
```

Comment: It only affect on splash screen not in main screen. But anyway i solved it u know

Answer (score -1):

Try to change code as below:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
 statusBarColor: Colors.white
 ));
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Is it maybe because my apps went fullscreen mode or smth